# Is there a name for the propositional tautology (and it's associated rule) $Q\Rightarrow(P\Rightarrow Q)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

I have the tautology $Q\Rightarrow(P\Rightarrow Q)$. I can prove this intuitionistically:

```
Rule 
  Conclusion
    Q=>(P=>Q)
  Proof
    Suppose
      Q
    Hence
      Suppose
        P
      Hence
        Q
      P=>Q
    Q=>(P=>Q)
```

This gives the corresponding inference rule:

$$
\frac{Q}{P\Rightarrow Q}\quad\text{[VacuousImplicationIntroduction]}
$$

The proof, which relies on the tautology, is:

```
Rule (VacuousImplicationIntroduction)
  Premise
    Q
  Conclusion
    P=>Q
  Proof
    Q=>(P=>Q)
    Q
    P=>Q by ModusPonens
```

I've called this rule 'vacuous implication introduction', which is a pretty poor name. Is there a standard or at least a better one?

Comment: It is basically [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) : $P \to (Q \lor P)$.

Comment: Let me try to work out why you've written that...

Comment: Presumably the two rules are equivalent...

Comment: In classical logic: YES. In Natural Deduction (Intuitionistically) $\dfrac {P} {Q \to P}$ is simply $\to$-intro.

Comment: The tautology $Q \to (P \to Q)$ was named *Simp* by W&R is their *Principia Mathematica* [2.02]; they proved it from their *Add* axiom: $Q \to (P \lor Q)$ [1.03] with a simple substitution: $\lnot P$ in place of $P$ **and** the fact that in *PM* system they have the definitional abbreviation: $P \to Q$ in place of $\lnot P \lor Q$, that obviously made the system "classical".

Comment: Okay, I cheated and looked at your answers before working out the equivalence myself. My excuse is you hardly gave me any time.

Comment: By the way, I've made some progress on my implementation of Propositional Logic since the last time you kindly helped me out: https://github.com/jecs-imperial/Propositional-Logic

Comment: Well it appears I have one up on Whitehead and Russell then because I haven't had to employ addition or had to equate logical consequence with the material conditional...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different authors have called the formula (not the rule) different names.

I've seen 'positive paradox', 'simplification', and 'Simp'.

I prefer to call the formula [p => (q => p)] or CpCqp in Polish notation, recursive variable prefixing.  Why?  Because under the the rule of detachment (also called modus ponens) it allows you to prefix any formula with a variable.  And since you can do that for any formula, you can recursively prefix each new formula with a variable in a proof sequence with prefixed formulas.  Or perhaps better, it allows to demonstrate metalogically that where 't' indicates a theorem or an axiom, that

$\vdash$Ca$_1$Ca$_2$...Ca$_n$t

CpCqp may look dull, but taking it as the only axiom under the rule of condensed detachment, which I'll call {CpCqp}, any theorem t which replaces CpCqp as the sole axiom has the same consequences as {CpCqp}.

In other words, where $\vdash$t in {CpCqp},

{t} |-| {CpCqp}

where |-| indicates deductive equivalence.

Not many non-trivial systems have that sort of property.

Comment: An interesting comment! I'm not sure I like 'positive paradox' either, and 'simplification' is definitely out, it's too generic. To be honest it's the rule that really needs a name. I take your point about recursion, you can keep applying the rule, however I think the word 'recursion' is a bit heavy, although I know that's a vague excuse. The word 'prefix' has possibilities, though. I'm going to go with 'PrefixedImplicationIntroduction' unless someone comes up with something better. I'm genuinely surprised the rule doesn't have a name.

Comment: Also, given that an alternative to 'implication introduction' is 'conditional proof' you could have 'unconditional proof' or, that word again, 'vacuous proof'.

Comment: The use of 'simplication' is out because it's used for conjunction elimination. And 'positive paradox' I can't find anywhere, although I like it.

Comment: @JamesSmith Here's an example of someone using the term 'positive paradox': https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/papers/mingles.pdf

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Cheers Doug. In that case I'll add it as the main label for the result.

Comment: Cool, I've adjusted [Positive paradox](https://github.com/jecs-imperial/Propositional-Logic/blob/master/Minimal/Derived%20rules/Positive%20paradox.fls) accordingly.

Comment: @JamesSmith "Simp" is used by Arthur Prior in the second appendix of his textbook "Formal Logic".  It also gets called "K" such as here: http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/BCK-page.htm.  Prior had a paper named "Logicians at Play; or Syll, Simp, and Hilbert."

Comment: Cheers, Doug. I'm a fan of Arthur Prior so I've put Simp back. I once wrote a paper on temporal logic in a week with no previous knowledge of the subject in order to demonstrate to some idiots at Imperial that I wasn't thick. There is a quote from Prior at the top, which I thought fitting at the time. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.7459v4.pdf